# Cant log into Hotmail

Tags: email

I am having the issue for about a month now, I used Lubuntu and then switched to Ubuntu; it started with Opera, I tried with Firefox, Chromium, Chrome, etc., the result is allways the same, I can not log to my Hotmail account; if I switch ti Windows, then I have no issue at all, except with Opera.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please describe what happens in more detail. Also, let us know which version of Ubuntu and browsers you're running. I can access Hotmail just fine with Firefox 10.0 on Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to ensure you're using the correct password; did you save your password on your windows browsers?  Have you changed it?

Another possibility is that your system's clock may not be properly set.  If you're dual booting, you may have told Ubuntu you're using UTC time, when the system clock is actually set to your local time zone.  This makes it impossible to create a secure internet connection (SSL connection) because the timestamps on the network traffic will be too far apart.

So: 
1) Check that the password is correct.
2) Check your system time is correct.